# Array of Lists of Lists

Tags: c#, arrays, list

I am trying to make an array of lists of lists, and the whole thing is confusing me. I want the array to be the larger thing, so I did `List<List<int>>[] arr = new List<List<int>>[5]`, but after I add a few items, I need to access them via `arr.ElementAt(1).ElementAt(1)[1]`, but shouldn't it be the other way around (the `[1]` being at the start)?

All I am trying to do is just fill the whole three dimensions, but when I try to add the last dimension via `arr[1].ElementAt(1).Add(...)` or `arr.ElementAt(1)[1].Add(...)` (wasn't sure which one to use, both didn't work) I get an arror saying I am trying to add a value to a null list

Comment: `ElementAt` works for arrays as well.

Comment: You need to initialize your lists.  Also I'd either just do `List<List<List<int>>>` or `int[][][]`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to instantiate your `List<List<int>>`s before you use them

```
arr[0] = new List<List<int>>();
arr[0].Add(new List<int>());
arr[0][0].Add(5);
///etc...
```

another note:  do you see how I'm using `[]` brackets on my `List`s?  that **is** supported.

Answer (score 0):

```
new List<List<int>>[5]
```

Is actually an array of List of List of int, but you can still call ElementAt() on it as an array implements IEnumerable.

Answer (score 0):

The following shows different interactions with your desired data structure to add and verify elements.

```
var arr = new List<List<int>>[]
    {
        new List<List<int>>()
        {
            new List<int>() { 1, 3, 5 },
            new List<int>() { 2, 4, 6 },
        },
        new List<List<int>>() { new List<int>() },
        new List<List<int>>() { new List<int>() },
        new List<List<int>>() { new List<int>() },
        new List<List<int>>() { new List<int>() },
    };
Assert.AreEqual(4, arr[0].ElementAt(1).ElementAt(1));
Assert.AreEqual(3, arr[0].ElementAt(1).Count);
arr[0].ElementAt(1).Add(8);
Assert.AreEqual(4, arr[0].ElementAt(1).Count);
Assert.AreEqual(8, arr[0].ElementAt(1).ElementAt(3));
```